# MYSQL - somar coluna e calcular dias em atraso de uma data e ordenar pelo maior atraso

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá,

Suponhamos que tenho uma tabela `tb_fatura` com o seguintes campos e valores:

```
id | transacao_id | valor    | vencimento
1  | 1            | 1109.97  | 2020-02-19
2  | 1            | 10,      | 2019-05-01
```

Eu quero `somar` a coluna `valor`, `calcular` os `dias em atraso do vencimento` e ordenar pelo maior atraso.

Com a query abaixo eu até consigo algum tipo de resultado, mas ainda não é o que preciso:

```
SELECT *, SUM(valor) AS total, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), vencimento) as atraso
FROM tb_fatura
WHERE transacao_id = 1
GROUP BY transacao_id
```

Isto me tras o seguinte resultado:

```
id | transacao_id | valor   | vencimento | total   | atraso
1  | 1            | 1109.97 | 2020-02-19 | 1119.97 | 91
```

Isto não me atende porque preciso ordenar pelo maior atraso e mesmo adicionando `order by`, não consegui! Fazer isto é possivel ?

Comment: acho q precisa somar os dias de atraso não é? algo como `SUM(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), vencimento))`

Comment: Não preciso somar os dias em atraso, preciso somente obter o maior atraso! a soma deve ser feita somente para o valor!

Comment: então `MAX` não funciona?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Respondendo com base no comentário, basta usar um `MAX` onde calcula a diferença de dias (atraso):

```
SELECT SUM(valor) AS total, MAX(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), vencimento)) as atraso
  FROM tb_fatura
 WHERE transacao_id = 1
 GROUP BY transacao_id;
```

Pode ver funcionando no [http://sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32ce8d/4)

Comment: quem negativou pode explicar o que está de ruim, se a resposta mostra uma solução para o problema, e ainda mostra um exemplo funcionando?

Comment: Funcionou para mim, muito obrigado pela resposta! E sinceramente não entendo o motivo da negativação da questão e resposta! Não acho que essa questão e/ou resposta seja de tão baixo nível a ponto de ser desqualificada!